# Dealing with values having comma in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which has 8 columns. Out of 8, 2 columns have value which contains `,` e.g. `2,134`

For processing I need to convert data into numeric (float)

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 90181 entries, 0 to 90180
Data columns (total 8 columns):
user_id                        90181 non-null object
location_id                    90181 non-null int64
is_shift_accepted              90181 non-null int64
shift_accepted_role            90179 non-null float64
shift_accepted_specialities    89973 non-null float64
distance                       90144 non-null object
years_of_experience            80604 non-null float64
shift_id                       90181 non-null object
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 5.5+ MB
```

Now lets convert into numeric

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.dtypes
user_id                        float64
location_id                      int64
is_shift_accepted                int64
shift_accepted_role            float64
shift_accepted_specialities    float64
distance                       float64
years_of_experience            float64
shift_id                       float64
dtype: object
```

Now checking null values -

```
# checking for missing values if any
df.isnull().sum()
user_id                        89943
location_id                        0
is_shift_accepted                  0
shift_accepted_role                2
shift_accepted_specialities      208
distance                         249
years_of_experience             9577
shift_id                       90042
dtype: int64
```

Here `user_id` and `shift_id` having values as `,` in them, giving the highest null count, though it has a not-null value. Is it due to `,` present in it? What is the correct way to pre-process this data?

Here is how data looks like

[image]

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv('data.csv', thousands=',')`

Comment: @jezrael: Still same issue.

Comment: hmmm, is possible see data of csv, first 5 rows?

Comment: @jezrael: I have updated the details. Please check

Comment: hmm, it seems some data related problem, so necessar share your csv, if possible.

Comment: Just testing `df = pd.read_csv('shift-reco.csv', thousands=',')` and working correctly.

Comment: @jezrael: Oh yeah, I dont know where did I miss. It works fine. Can you tell me how it resolved issue?

Comment: Only I run code ;)

Comment: I mean what difference `thousands=','` does make?

Comment: it convert `1` to empty spaces if thousands